# Brown and yellow spots on dracaena (corn plant) only in light middle areas?

Tags: dracaena

[image]
[image]
[image]

After doing a bunch of google'ing I first thought the roots might have rot so I repotted and the roots looked perfectly healthy. Then I thought maybe I'm over watering or it has some kind of fungal disease so I reduced watering but that didn't seem to help. I also checked for mites or other pests but didn't find anything. Finally, i tested the soil and tap water PH and they seemed normal as well.

The plant overall "looks" healthy but the brown spots are intensifying and I'm very worried. I ordered some fungicide with the hopes that that's the problem but I'm basically guessing at this point.

If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate some help.